# Custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have a custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping class that interprets a special annotation as part of its mapping criteria.  It is being instantiated as a bean thusly:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new VersionRangeRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

But when I create a MockMvc object for testing (with standaloneSetup) this mapping handler isn't being used.  Without the extra annotation being taken into account, the mapping fails because I have multiple controller methods with the same @RequestMapping.  The annotation is what differentiates them.

How can I configure MockMvc to use this custom mapping handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I configure MockMvc to use this custom mapping handler?

As of Spring Framework 4.3.x, it is currently not possible to register a custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` with the `standaloneSetup()` builder for `MockMvc`.

However, the team is considering adding such support in Spring Framework 5.0.

See [SPR-15472](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15472) for further details.

Comment: Does that mean it is possible when using webAppContextSetup?

Comment: I believe while using webAppContextSetup it had worked well. I faced the same problem and in my case the problem was only in mockMvc standaloneSetup. But it was fixed with "setCustomHandlerMapping()" method

Answer (score 1):

For those who's still in search, since Spring updated to version 5.0 (I believe) the custom MockMvc requestHandlerMapping configuration was introduced.

Example of usage:

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyAwesomeController())
        .setCustomHandlerMapping(() -> new MyAwesomeRequestMappingHandlerMapping())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure with override getRequestMappingHandlerMapping method of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new VersionRangeRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```